# Custom Text Box filter Layered Navigation in Magento1.9

Tags: php, filter, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I need to show the custom textbox in Layered Navigation in Magento1.9 and to filter also like Magento's default attribute in "Shop By" layered navigation.I have shown a clue from this link [Magento: textbox instead of multi select in layered navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480558/magento-textbox-instead-of-multi-select-in-layered-navigation). But there is no clue of filtering like the functionality of Shop By's filter in layered navigation in Magento1.9.I can not understand how to do it.And I have searched a lot in google, but there is no fruitful result in google. If any one knows about it, please reply me.

Comment: are you creating a module?

Comment: No, I can't understand it is needed to create a module or not. How will I go forward for this functionality after creating a custom Module. I need some clue.

Comment: you have to rewrite the layer block and layer model for custom layered navigation.